# Python socket загрузка страниц HTML

Tags: python

Есть нужда загрузить N - количество страниц(HTML код) используя сокет.
Т.к в скорость загрузки через requests.get(url) меня не удовлетворяет (нужно загрузить более 100 000 страниц)..

Нашел бенчмарк в сети и низкоуровневая решение оказалось более предпочтительнее.

> Скрипт (https://pastebin.com/mH2ASEGX) в 100 итераций получает главную страницу vk.com и ищет на ней
>   наличие паттерна — типичные действия при парсинге. Резульаты
>   следующие:

- ('testUrllib()', 19.59859853472629)
- ('testUrllib2()', 22.586007300934412)
- ('testHttplib()', 16.670537860489773)
- ('testSocket()', 1.5129479809538537)
- ('testRequests()', 9.380710576092)
- ('testPycurl()', 17.76420596649031)

Что я имею сейчас.

```
import socket
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
listURL = [
'/catalog?prod=737461', '/catalog?prod=1278496',
'/catalog?prod=1216350', '/catalog?prod=358994',
'/catalog?prod=1265075', '/catalog?prod=288706',
'/catalog?prod=737461', '/catalog?prod=1278496',
'/catalog?prod=1216350', '/catalog?prod=358994',
'/catalog?prod=1265075', '/catalog?prod=288706',
'/catalog?prod=737461', '/catalog?prod=1278496',
'/catalog?prod=1216350', '/catalog?prod=358994',
'/catalog?prod=1265075', '/catalog?prod=288706',
]


def __description(data):
    """!
    @brief Парсер описание книги
    @param [in] str url
    @return str
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(data), 'html.parser')
    last_links = soup.find_all('span', itemprop = "description")
    description = last_links[0].text
    return description

def start():
    """!
    @brief Скачивание и обработка страниц о книге
    """
    start_time = time.clock()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    WebAddress = "www.flip.kz"
    s.connect((WebAddress, 80))
    uagent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)'
    for iterator in listURL:
        patch = "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n" % (iterator, WebAddress, uagent)
        s.sendall(patch.encode())
        string = ""
        data = s.recv(65535)
        string += data.decode('utf-8')   
        print(string)
        print(__description(string))
        print("======================================")
    s.close
    print(time.clock() - start_time, "seconds")
    print('========')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Comment: Во-первых, нужно было пробовать применять очевидные оптимизации вроде многопоточности/асинхронности и keep-alive (неважно с чем, хоть с requests, хоть с urllib2, хоть с aiohttp). Во-вторых, непонятно в чём вопрос, если здесь присутствует вроде как готовый код

Comment: В бенчмарке, кстати, код testSocket вопиюще неправильный с кучей ошибок, и я бы ему не доверял. А вы перекопипастили себе эти ошибки

Comment: Возможно я эту кухню не правильно готовил но в многопоточном скачивание у меня был выигрыш всего лишь в 3 секунды.
Да и  keep-alive при requests я использовал.
        uagent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)'
        headers = {'User-Agent': uagent}
        rc = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)

Comment: Вообще, если вы внимательно перепроверите код бенчмарка и все его переменные, то увидите, что **ни одна функция не смогла скачать страницу vk.com** (в `print counter` всегда печатаются только нули): они то отлупливаются на редиректы, то упираются в badbrowser.php, то ещё какой-нибудь хлам. Поэтому доверять ему нельзя вообще

Comment: @andreymal
Асинхронное выполнение https://pastebin.com/TcAx74UH
Многопоточное выполнение https://pastebin.com/PG1qTnD4
Естественно я это побывал.

Comment: Возможно на момент написание бенчмарка он работал структура сайта могла сменится ... меня волнуют результаты точнее сказать время затраты на скачивание страницы.

Comment: Во-первых, в первой ссылке нет ничего про асинхронность; во-вторых, по второй ссылке я не увидел нормального измерения времени; в третьих, неизвестно что такое `InfoByPost`, а там теоретически может стоять целая блокировка, тормозящая всё; в-четвёртых, вам нужно разобраться, почему конкретно не получается достаточной производительности — вполне возможно, что, например, сервер банально ограничивает число запросов с одного IP-адреса и вы в принципе не сможете качать быстрее чем сейчас, или что-то вроде того

Comment: В-пятых, администраторы сервера заметят повышенную нагрузку на сайт и быстренько забанят вас по айпишнику ;) Я вот наборот добавляю искусственную задержку в секунду-две между запросами, чтобы не нарваться на бан

Comment: https://pastebin.com/s2eigmjU вот InfoByPost
там используется requests.get()
По моему он блокирует порт при выполнение в много поточном/асинхроном варианте исполнение.
Вот кстати график построенный профилировщиком тут явно видно слабое место https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM9uB.png

Comment: @andreymal
Ну насчет администраторов это не проблема задержку поставить можно в любой момент.

Comment: Когда забанят по айпишнику, будет поздно) Хорошо если через время разбанится, а я вот год назад скачивал много картинок с одного картинкохостинга, даже с паузами в одну-две секунды — не разбанили до сих пор

Comment: Ваша картинка от профилировщика показывает 89% как раз в модуле socket, так что от выкидывания requests вы по сути не выиграете вообще ничего. Однако она не показывает, **почему** socket так тормозит и ничего не сообщает про многопоточность, асинхронность и серверные ограничения, поэтому профилировщик здесь бесполезен и нужно думать головой. Если у меня дойдут сегодня руки, попробую сам покачать что-нибудь

Comment: @andreymal
Спасибо.
Если будут с подвижки в этом направление напишите обязательно.

Comment: @andreymal Кстати есть код моего проекта на github который я хочу оптимизировать если что то надумаете то кинте pull request.
https://github.com/hays0503/crawler_book

Comment: Кстати, я сейчас проверил, в моей системе (Arch Linux) `time.clock()` не учитывает время ожидания ответа в сокете — он измеряет только время, которое процесс фактически работает, а не ожидает чего-то, поэтому использовать его для измерения производительности сетевых приложений нельзя. Английский Stack Overflow [предлагает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12279603) `timer = time.clock if sys.platform == 'win32' else time.time`, а вообще наверно лучше использовать тот самый timeit

Comment: Да я слышал про timeit просто после того как я прогонял свой проект на разных профилировщиках хотел посмотреть как в "вакуме" быстро выполнится тот или иная версия скачивания страниц.
У меня Win7 Python3.7 32bit.

Comment: Начал пробовать измерять и наткнулся на любопытный факт: в браузере всё качается быстро, а без браузера быстрым является только первый запрос, а второй и последующий выжидают минимум четыре секунды (причём неважно как качать: и через requests, и через urllib, да я даже попробовал через wget и netcat вообще без питона — задержка всё равно есть!). Похоже, на сервере всё-таки имеется ограничение число запросов, но я пока не понял его алгоритма (точно не по User-Agent, так как я его указывал), и решать проблему нужно не сокетами, а выяснением этого алгоритма. Но это уже не совсем по теме вопроса

Comment: Если установить `Cookie: re_chg=1`, то задержка в четыре секунды исчезает (правда, похоже, вместо неё остаётся задержка в одну секунду, но точно не проверял). Возможно, корректная обработка кук и является решением вашей проблемы, и можно спокойно использовать requests.get в один поток, всего лишь добавив обработку кук. Многопоточность или голые сокеты не помогут, потому что на сервере стоит ограничение. (Ну и попутно мораль: профилировщик не всемогущий и его отчёты надо интерпретировать с умом, вот :)

Comment: @andreymal
Прекрасно это уже продвижение. Буду копать в эту сторону.
Профилировщик это всего лишь "лакмусовая бумажка". =)